# How height: auto works in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, height

In CSS and HTML how does `height: auto` work? What do browsers consider while calculating height of the element, for which `height` is set to `auto`?

Comment: It's complicated, dependant on many factors, and [described in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property).

Answer (score 4):

You can split two cases:

- **div and other containers**: the height is the one the browser will use if you don't specify anything, trying to contain the element contents. (read Mathijs's answer for more details)
- **images and other block elements** with intrinsic dimensions (width and height): if you specify the width, then "height: auto" will scale proportionally.

So, in other words, is useless unless you need to reset the browser behaviour or keep proportions to some objects.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an excerpt on this [copied from the W3C CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#root-height)

> If it only has inline-level children, the height is the distance
>   between the top of the topmost line box and the bottom of the
>   bottommost line box.
>
> If it has block-level children, the height is the distance between the
>   top margin-edge of the topmost block-level child box and the bottom
>   margin-edge of the bottommost block-level child box.
>
> Absolutely positioned children are ignored, and relatively positioned
>   boxes are considered without their offset. Note that the child box may
>   be an anonymous block box.
>
> In addition, if the element has any floating descendants whose bottom
>   margin edge is below the element's bottom content edge, then the
>   height is increased to include those edges. Only floats that
>   participate in this block formatting context are taken into account,
>   e.g., floats inside absolutely positioned descendants or other floats
>   are not.